# Does an Embedded Content Security Policy (CSP) Enforcement ruin a "regular" CSP?

Tags: web-browser, http, web, content-security-policy

I recently read a W3C Working Draft about the Embedded Enforcement of a Content Security Policy (CSP).

> This document defines a mechanism by which a web page can embed a nested browsing context if and only if it agrees to enforce a particular set of restrictions upon itself.
>   **Source**: [Content Security Policy: Embedded Enforcement](https://www.w3.org/TR/csp-embedded-enforcement/)

Unless I understood it completely wrong, does this Embedding-CSP not ruin the fundamentals of CSP completely?

*In a case wherin you can inject HTML (with an iframe) or JS (XSS) you'd be able to set such "Embedded CSP" attribute? That overwrites the CSP from the original HTTP response? That seems undesirable.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not at all.**

Let's say I build my website `supersite.com` with a lot of JS, so I want it to be able to run scripts, but I also want to put some adds, but I don't want it to be dynamic and thus doesn't execute `script`.

The problem is that usually, my add provider do include script. To avoid this, I explically tell him that I do not want script, I'll then set the following `iframe`:

`<iframe src="http://addprovider.com/?site=mywebsite" csp="script-src 'none'"></iframe>`

While sending the `GET` request to `addprovider.com`, the following header will be set :

`Embedding-CSP: script-src 'none'`

From there, `addprovider.com` knows that if it puts `script`, `supersite.com` will refused to execute the script and thus decide to put some fancy images instead. While sending back the answer, `addprovider.com` shows that it accepts the given policy by setting the following header:

`Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none'`

If `addprovider.com` try to cheat and send back that its answer is csp complient but doesn't, `supersite.com` the response will be blocked.
If `addprovider` doesn't return csp or return a csp that doesn't match or enforce the given `csp`, the response will be blocked too.

---

How is it usefull ? This are the 2 alternatives atm :

- Set a `CSP` on `supersite.com`, with header or meta tag : `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">`. Howewer, this `CSP` will not apply to the embedded `addprovider.com` !
- Use `sandbox` attributes. Howewer, this it too broad. You can only block all `script` or none. You can't specify different locations while you can do with `CSP`